# I'm trying to understand recursion in Tcl, but every time the recursion finishes it throws errors

Tags: loops, recursion, tcl, procedure, proc

I'm new to TCL, and trying to set up a simple recursion loop. The code I have works up until the recursion finishes, then it begins throwing errors.  This is my code:

```
set testNum 0

proc raiseTest { a } {
    puts $a
    if { $a == 5 } {
        puts "Done!"
    } elseif { $a != 5 } {
        incr a
        puts "Going!"
        [raiseTest $a]
    } 
    
}

[ raiseTest $testNum ]
```

Once the proc reaches 5 and finishes it's last loop, I get hit with an *invalid command name ""* error followed by a ton of *invoked from within* errors and I have no idea why. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Why do you have brackets around the calls to `raiseTest`?

Comment: The simple answer being that I have no idea what I'm doing, thank you!

Comment: You can also look into using Tcl's `tailcall` command: `tailcall raiseTest $a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things

1. You call a procedure without using the square brackets. You only use the square brackets when you need to capture the procedure's return value, which is not in this case
2. The `elseif {$a != 5}` is redundant, you can replace it with just `else`

To further discuss point #1, the line right after `puts "Going!"`, which reads:

```
        [raiseTest $a]
```

This line calls `raiseTest $a`, then because of the square brackets, capture the output of that call (an empty string because nothing was returned) and use that as the name of a proc and call it.

Here is an example:

```
proc foo {} {
    puts "foo"
    return "bar"
}

proc bar {} {
    puts "bar"
}

foo    ;# prints "foo"
[foo]  ;# prints "foo", then "bar""
```

That being said, the code should look like this, with the square brackets removed:

```
proc raiseTest { a } {
    puts "a=$a"
    if { $a == 5 } {
        puts "Done!"
    } else {
        incr a
        puts "Going!"
        raiseTest $a
    }
}

set testNum 0
raiseTest $testNum
```